# How to fix connection loss in VM?

Tags: linux, cron, virtual-machine

My virtual machine loses the internet connection sometimes on linux and I need to stay connected constantly. So I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com 
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then 
    service network-manager restart
fi
```

When I run this script in the console it works but using a `cron` I get:

```
network-manager: unrecognized service
```

What can I do to make this work, or what another approach may I use?

Answer (score -1):

If you are entering your service name correctly, I think your problem causes from lack of Environment Variables.

From `service` command manual:

> service runs a System V init script in as predictable environment as
>   possible.

It's better to use full path of your service file like: `/etc/init.d/network-manager`

Therefor for restarting your service use: `/etc/init.d/network-manager restart`

Comment: Unfortunately network-manager is not inside /etc/init.d/ I tried to locate this but didn't found it, even doing ps command and it is the only way to be reconnected